# How to fix Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'call' of undefined in fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, phonegap, fullcalendar-4

im developing an apps using phonegap and need to use fullcalendar 'selectable' functionalities. the apps works fine in phone. but when installed to tablet, tapping on any of the calendar will shows this error:

> 07-25 16:12:37.676: I/chromium(4707): [INFO:CONSOLE(128)] "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'call' of undefined", source: file:///android_asset/www/apis/fullcalendar/core/main.js (128)

Why it only happens on tablet but on my phone it is working fine

these are the scripts that i've imported in my html:

```
<link href='apis/fullcalendar/core/main.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<link href='apis/fullcalendar/daygrid/main.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<script src='apis/fullcalendar/core/main.js'></script>
<script src='apis/fullcalendar/interaction/main.js'></script>
<script src='apis/fullcalendar/daygrid/main.js'></script>
```

and this is how i create my calendar

```
    var today = moment().format('YYYY[-]MM[-]DD');
    var eventList = new Array();

    $.each(
        holidayDateList,
        function(i,v) {
            var events = {
                title: holidayNameList[i],
                start: v,
                backgroundColor: "#8c8c8c"
            };

            eventList.push(events);
        });

    $.each(
        offdayServerDateList,
        function(i,v) {
            var events = {
                title: offdayServerReasonList[i],
                start: v
            };

            eventList.push(events);
        });

    $.each(
        offdayDateList,
        function(i,v) {
            var events = {
                title: offdayReasonList[i],
                start: v
            };

            eventList.push(events);
        });

    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

    var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
        plugins: [ 'interaction', 'dayGrid' ],
        defaultDate: today,
        editable: false,
        selectable: true,
        selectMirror: true,
        select: function(arg) {
            var isToday = moment(arg.start).format('YYYY[-]MM[-]DD') == today;
            var isAfterToday = moment(arg.start).isAfter(today);
            var isHolidayDate = holidayDateList.indexOf(moment(arg.start).format('YYYY[-]MM[-]DD')) >= 0;
            var isOffdayDate = offdayServerDateList.indexOf(moment(arg.start).format('YYYY[-]MM[-]DD')) >= 0;

            if((isAfterToday || isToday) && !isHolidayDate && !isOffdayDate) {
                $("#dialog-form").dialog("open");
            }
        },
        eventLimit: true,
        eventClick: function(info) {
            var isOffdayDate = offdayServerDateList.indexOf(moment(info.event.start).format('YYYY[-]MM[-]DD')) >= 0;

            if(isOffdayDate) {
                alert("Open delete reason dialog for " + moment(info.event.start).format('YYYY[-]MM[-]DD'));
            } else {
                alert(info.event.title);
            }
        },
        events: eventList
    });

    calendar.render();
```

UPDATE: i use samsung j5 pro (android oreo) for my phone testing device which the device that can works without any problem. the device that have problem is my samsung galaxy tab 3(android kitkat). also tried to install the apps on nox player set as phone and table. but cannot work either

Comment: which tablet? Which O/S (and version)? Which browser (and version)? Can we see your code please? We can't guess the details of your environment. It's not a known issue for it to just totally fail to work on any "tablet", so we need some specifics. It might also help to know the same details about the phone where it works, so we can compare.

Comment: @ADyson i have updated some details. hope it helps

Comment: Can you load https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/dxXeBW in a browser (e.g. Chrome) on your tablet and see if you have an issue with selecting? (P.S. I had to comment out a lot of code because I don't have access to your event data, but perhaps you could reintroduce that into the CodePen to make it more accurate to your exact code). The purpose of testing in the browser is to see if the issue might be related to phonegap.

Comment: @ADyson tried on chrome 75.0.3770.143 app but nothing shows up. i even change console.log to alert. but nothing pops up

Comment: Are you aware of the settings here: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/touch ? You may need to press for longer to initiate the select event.

Comment: @ADyson sorry i forgot about that. i actually adjust the code on my side at Interaction/main.js and remove the long press. i've tried the long press on my tab and seems like its working now. but the apps still fails and shows the same error

Comment: @ADyson i will revert my changes and see if that solves the problem

Comment: @ADyson UPDATED: reverted the Interaction/main.js to the original version but same error

Comment: and is that error reproduced by running the CodePen as well, or just the phonegap version?

Comment: @ADyson no the codepen works fine on my tab. so no error is shown on the chrome console. so its only happen on the phonegap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like when i run the code on my tab. The js doesn't recognize any of the matches method provided in Core/main.js

I need to add webkitMatchesSelector during the matches method selection on line 107 so the code use that matches method instead if others are undefined.

Original:

```
var matchesMethod = Element.prototype.matches ||
Element.prototype.matchesSelector ||
Element.prototype.msMatchesSelector;
```

Updated:

```
var matchesMethod = Element.prototype.matches ||
Element.prototype.matchesSelector ||
Element.prototype.msMatchesSelector || 
Element.prototype.webkitMatchesSelector; // add this
```

reference: https://github.com/matsko/ng4-animations-preview/issues/1